# Display maximum two lines and show fading after two lines only

Tags: html, css, css-position

Here is the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ucdh09by/4/) of existing implementation.

Currently I am displaying fading always. The requirement is fading should come if user has entered more than two lines. But that fading should not come when there is one line text or two line text with enough space. Is it possible to implement using pure CSS?

Note: I can not set fix height as Div has to occupy only one line height if user has entered only one line.

```
.testWrapOverflowFade {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 2.4em; /* NOL = height in this class/height in after class. Here it is 2.4/1.2 = 2. Change it to 3.6em for display 3 lines. */
}
.testWrapOverflowFade:after {    
    content: "";
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 10%;
    height: 1.2em;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%);
}

<div class="testWrapOverflowFade">This is a long text this is a long text 2  this is a long text 3  this is a long text 4  this is a long text 5  this is a long text6  this is a long text7  this is a long text 8  this is a long text 9  this is a long text 10  this is a long text 11  this is a long text12 </div>
```

**---- UPDATE ----**
Here is the hover issue. I highlighted it with yellow color.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Let us see what is possible pure CSS:

1. Set `max-height: 2.4em` for the container - you can use this to adjust the number of lines you need.
2. Set `top: 1.2em` for the `after` to put the *fader* in the second line - you can use this to put the *fader* at the end of the last line.

> The requirement is fading should come if user has entered more than
>   two lines. But that fading should not come when there is one line text
>   or two line text with enough space.

*One line of text*: As the `after` is behind the container it will be hidden behind.

*More than 2 lines*: `max-height` solves this for us.

*Two line text with enough space*: for this you need JS to hide the *fader* (not an issue if the *fader* matches the background)

See demo below - background set to red for illustration:

```css
.testWrapOverflowFade {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 2.4em;
}
.testWrapOverflowFade:after {
  content: "";
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 1.2em;
  width: 10%;
  height: 1.2em;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="testWrapOverflowFade">This is a long text this is a long text This is a long text this is a long text This is a long text this is a long text 
</div>
```

Comment: yeah, it happens :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I already implemented it by setting max-height and top but problem is that I have a special effect for fading on hover. Whenever I am hovering on that div I can see that special effect of fading. I am not sure why it's not getting hide the way it's happening in JSFiddle.

Comment: @alok_dida can you update the fiddle in your question? I didn't get you...

Comment: @alok_dida you missed a semi-colon after `top: 1.2em` in your fiddle above... corrected: https://jsfiddle.net/a3397arx/